# How to use hover not included in the react code?

Tags: css, reactjs, hover, less

I have the following CSS configuration

```
.my-page {
      &-link {
        font-weight: normal;
        color: green;

        &:hover {
          text-decoration: underline;
          font-weight: 500;
          color: #006cbc;
        }
   }
}
```

When I include it in my react component, it does not somehow include hover.

I have included "my-page-link" and "my=page-link-hover" as classNames and both do not work.

```
  <SomeComponent
                      name="here."
                      variant="primary"
                      label="here."
                      className="my-page-link"
                      onClick={this.onEditPaymentMethodModalShow}

                    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your SASS code is broken. You're missing a closing curly bracket.
Try this:

```
.my-page {
  &-link {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: green;

    &:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: #006cbc;
    }
  }
}
```

Also you can use the [SASS playground](https://sass.js.org/) to make sure that you get what you expect.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: what should be the classname ?

Comment: Here is the result of this SASS, so as you can see the class name should remain as you wrote it: ```.my-page-link {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: green;
}

.my-page-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #006cbc;
}```